# How to loop a triangle-shaped piece into n-gon

Tags: modifiers, looping

I have a triangle with an angle of 45 degrees, I need to loop it so that I get an octagon with the same pattern on each of 8 "slices"

I could use a screw modifier, but it messes up edges inside of a slice

[image]

Comment: You can use array with an empty